# Use setIndexedTypes or setTypeMetadata methods on CacheConfiguration to enable. Ignite Error

Tags: in-memory-database, ignite

I am trying out the simple person example for a read through cache. Set up basic table and here is my code that i am trying to run

```
 IgniteConfiguration cfg = new IgniteConfiguration();
        cfg.setClientMode(true);
        cfg.setPeerClassLoadingEnabled(true);

        // Create store factory.
        CacheJdbcPojoStoreFactory storeFactory = new CacheJdbcPojoStoreFactory();
        storeFactory.setDataSourceBean("dataSource");

        CacheConfiguration sampleCache = CacheConfig.cache("sampleCache", storeFactory);
        sampleCache.setIndexedTypes(PersonKey.class,Person.class);
        cfg.setCacheConfiguration(sampleCache);



        Ignition.start("default-config1.xml");
        Ignite ignite=Ignition.ignite();

        IgniteCache<IncappconfigKey,INCAppConfig> cache =ignite.getOrCreateCache("sampleCache");
        cache.loadCache(null);

        SqlQuery  sqlQuery=new SqlQuery(Person.class,"id=?");
        cache.query(sqlQuery.setArgs(1l));
```

Am setting the index type still am getting the above error. Can some one please help. Stuck on this for some time now.

All the CacheConfig and other classes are auto generated by the import tool.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Use setIndexedTypes or setTypeMetadata methods on CacheConfiguration is the error

Comment: Share your full stack trace if you want to get an answer. No one can run your code because it contains custom classes.

Answer (score 0):

You did not pass in the configuration into Ignite. Just start Ignition with the `IgniteConfiguration` object you have initialized.

In short, it should be

```java
IgniteConfiguration cfg = new IgniteConfiguration();
        ...
        ...
Ignition.start(cfg);
        ...
```