# javax.cache.CacheException: Indexing is disabled for cache: test. Use setIndexedTypes or setTypeMetadata methods on CacheConfiguration to enable

Tags: apache-spark, apache-zeppelin, ignite

Similar question is asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39515011/use-setindexedtypes-or-settypemetadata-methods-on-cacheconfiguration-to-enable). However in this question I have tried to include more details and executable code if needed. Also here I am executing this code via Zeppelin.

Here is the code snippets from Zeppelin notebooks:

Notebook-1 - stores some data to ignite cache.

```
val ic = new IgniteContext(sc, () => new IgniteConfiguration())

val cacheConfig = new CacheConfiguration[Int, Int]()
    cacheConfig.setName("test")
    cacheConfig.setIndexedTypes(classOf[Int], classOf[Int])

val cacheRdd = ic.fromCache[Int,Int](cacheConfig)

cacheRdd.savePairs(sc.parallelize(1 to 10000, 10).map(i => (i, i)))
```

part - 2: Reading from the cache where we stored some data from notebook-1.

```
val ic = new IgniteContext(sc, () => new IgniteConfiguration())
val cacheConfig = new CacheConfiguration[Int, Int]()
  cacheConfig.setName("partitioned")
  cacheConfig.setIndexedTypes(classOf[Int], classOf[Int])

val ic = new IgniteContext(sc, () => new IgniteConfiguration())

val cacheRdd = ic.fromCache(cacheConfig)
cacheRdd.sql("select _val from Integer")
```

Code from first notebook is executed fine. However while executing second notebook it is failing with exception mentioned in header.

Full exception:

```
javax.cache.CacheException: Indexing is disabled for cache: test. Use setIndexedTypes or setTypeMetadata methods on CacheConfiguration to enable.
  at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.IgniteCacheProxy.validate(IgniteCacheProxy.java:831)
  at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.IgniteCacheProxy.query(IgniteCacheProxy.java:690)
  at org.apache.ignite.spark.IgniteRDD.sql(IgniteRDD.scala:147)
  ... 64 elided
```

Comment: Can you export both notebooks and provide them? Also please describe the steps how you start Spark, Ignite, etc. and run the test so that I can reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you should try same above code with creating a new cache. I think its referring to some old cache configuration with which the cache was initially created. Or destroy the cache and try recreating it with the same name and above mentioned configuration.